# How correct drag and drop group in konva.js, using scale?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs, react-konva

If I am trying use getTransform() into child of group, i can not get current points of polygon. What can I use with stage scale?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-tree-49utnt

I am trying to make validation for polygons.
blue polygon should be into grey polygon and do not intersect to anoter blue polygon.
It is correct, while i am do not use stage scale. How solve the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Get answer here in russian forum: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1439537